# If X and Y are random variables with the same distribution, prove that f(X) and f(Y) are random variables that have the same distribution.

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Suppose X is a RV on $(\Omega, \mathfrak{F}, P)$. Let f be Borel-measurable on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathfrak{B})$.

1 Show that f(X) is also a RV on $(\Omega, \mathfrak{F}, P)$.

2 Let Y ba  RV on $(\Omega', \mathfrak{F}', P')$ which has the same dist as X. Show that f(X) and f(Y) have the same dist.

1 Am I to show that $f(X(B))^{-1} \in \mathfrak{F}$  given $X^{-1}(B) \in \mathfrak{F}$ (our def of X being a RV) and $f^{-1}(B) \in \mathfrak{B}$ (our def of f being Borel-measurable)? It seems like all I have to do is make use of $f(X(B))^{-1} = X^{-1}(f^{-1}(B))$...

2 Am I to show that $\mathfrak{L}_{f(X)}((-\infty,x]) = \mathfrak{L}_{f(Y)}((-\infty,y])$ given $\mathfrak{L}_{X}((-\infty,x]) = \mathfrak{L}_{Y}((-\infty,y])$ ?

Here is my attempt:

$\mathfrak{L}_{X}((-\infty,x]) = \mathfrak{L}_{Y}((-\infty,y])$

$\to \mathfrak{L}_{X}(B) = \mathfrak{L}_{Y}(B)$ by corollary of Uniqueness Lemma

$\to \mathfrak{L}_{X}(f^{-1}(B)) = \mathfrak{L}_{Y}(f^{-1}(B))$ if we choose $B = f^{-1}(B)$

$\to P(X^{-1}(f^{-1}(B)) = P'(Y^{-1}(f^{-1}(B))$

$\to \mathfrak{L}_{f(X)}(B) = \mathfrak{L}_{f(Y)}(B)$

$\to \mathfrak{L}_{f(X)}((-\infty,x]) = \mathfrak{L}_{f(Y)}((-\infty,y])$ if we choose B = $(-\infty,x] or (-\infty,y]$

QED?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are using the fact that $X$ is a random variable, that $f$ is Borel measurable, and that pre-images obey the rule $Z^{-1}(B)=X^{-1}(f^{-1}(B))$ for $Z=f(X)$. Neither of the first two assumptions can be relaxed.
2. If $P(X\in A)=P'(Y\in A)$ for all $A\in\mathfrak B$, then 2. follows from the fact that
   $$
   P(f(X)\in A)=P(X\in f^{-1}(A))=\cdots=P'(f(Y)\in A)
   $$ and that $f^{-1}(A)\in\mathfrak B$ for all $B\in\mathfrak B$ since $f$ is assumed Borel measurable.

Comment: 1 Ugh...so I'm right?

2 Sorry for the confusion. I edited the post. Ugh...so I'm right?

Comment: 1. Yes, you're right (you just need some "for all $B\in\mathfrak B$" several places). 2. If $\mathcal{L}_Z$ is shorthand for the distribution, i.e. $P\circ Z^{-1}$, then almost. You want to write $P'(Y^{-1}(\cdots))$ instead of $P(Y^{-1}(\cdots))$ since $Y$ is defined on another probability space $(\Omega',\mathfrak F',P')$. There is also no need to write the first and last line.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot that I can short-cut stuff out only in my drafts and not on stackexchange or final submission.

Anyway, if the probability space is different, why again is it the same law? Just because the distributions are the same?

Comment: Yes, even if the probability spaces are different, you only need that $P\circ X^{-1}=P'\circ Y^{-1}$ and that $f$ is Borel measurable to conclude that $P\circ (f(X))^{-1}=P'\circ (f(Y))^{-1}$.

Comment: I'm going to assume that the answer to "why again is it the same law?" is yes too. Thanks!

Comment: I just wanted to write it out, since you're using both the term "law" and "distribution" and I couldn't tell if you thought there was a difference between the two.

Comment: Ah thanks. Btw, re "There is also no need to write the first and last line. ", do the first and last not represent the definition of distributions?

Comment: No, the distribution of $X$ is the probability measure $B\mapsto P(X\in B)$, where $B$ can be any Borel set, not just intervals.

Comment: Our references seem to pick definitions differently. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For 1: Show $(f \circ X)^{-1} (A) \in \mathfrak{F}$ for any $A \in \mathfrak{B}$.

For 2:

$P \{ \omega | F(X(\omega)) \in A \} = P \{ \omega | X(\omega) \in F^{-1}(A) \} = P' \{ \omega | Y(\omega) \in F^{-1}(A) \} = P' \{ \omega | F(Y(\omega)) \in A \}$.

Comment: @StefanHansen: Much appreciated. I completely missed that in the question.

Comment: 1 So that was the definition of what I was to show. Thanks. Am I right in thinking that the key to doing that is what I stated above (inverse of composition is the composition of inverses in reverse order)?

2 Is mine wrong? It looks like we stated the same thing in a different way.

Comment: For 1, You should write $(F \circ X)^{-1} (B)$ as $f(X(B))^{-1}$ makes no sense. For 2, you need to show that the distributions match on a collection of sets that generate $\mathfrak{B}$. You have two sets $(-\infty,x]$ and $(\infty, y]$ which have no relation to each other, so no, your's is not the same thing stated in a different way.

Comment: Thanks! For 1 small f does make sense since it is not a distribution function. For 2, sorry for the confusion. My reference defines distributions in terms of such intervals. By uniqueness lemma, I believe we are saying the same thing?