# Prove that $X_n = e^{(\theta S_n-n \ln \phi(\theta))}$ is martingale.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales

Let $\xi_1 \neq const.$ be a random variable with moment-generating function $\phi(\theta) = Ee^{(\theta \xi_1)}$. Let $S_n = \xi_1 + \dots \xi_n$. Prove that $X_n = e^{(\theta S_n-n \ln \phi(\theta))}$ is martingale.

I think that if $\xi_i$ are idd this is obviously because in this case $X_n=1$.

So in my opinion I should consider case if $\xi_i$ are not iid. But in this case I dont have any idea.

Comment: Hint: When you condition by $\mathcal F_{n-1}$ and take expectation, you can take $e^{\theta S_{n-1}}$ and $(n-1)\ln (\phi(\theta))$ out of the expectation

Comment: The result is not true in general when $(\xi_n)$ is not independent or not identically distributed hence the exercise is definitely about the i.i.d. case. If $(\xi_n)$ is i.i.d., this is indeed "obviously true" but not "because in this case $X_n=1$". Finally the hypothesis that $\xi_1$ is not almost surely constant, is unnecessary.

Comment: Why $X_n \neq 1$ ? We have that $X_n = \frac{e^{\theta S_n}}{\phi(\theta)^n}$ but if $(\xi_i)$ are i.i.d then $e^{\theta S_n}$ is moment-generating function of $S_n = \xi_1 + \dots + \xi_n$ so $e^{\theta S_n} = \phi(\theta)^n$. Could you tell me why am I wrong?

Comment: @Thomas Note that $\mathbb{E}e^{\theta S_n} = \phi(\theta)^n$, but, in general, $e^{\theta S_n} \neq \phi(\theta)^n$.

Comment: Of course, my mistake, sorry. So now I have $\mathbb{E}[X_n| \mathcal{F}_{n-1}] = \frac{e^{\theta S_{n-1}}}{\phi(\theta)^{n-1}} \cdot \mathbb{E}[\frac{e^{\xi_n}}{\phi(\theta)} | \mathcal{F}_{n-1}]$. What can I do in next step?

Comment: ... use the independence?

Comment: I think $\mathbb{E}[\frac{e^{\xi_n}}{\phi(\theta)}|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}] = \frac{1}{\phi(\theta)}\mathbb{E}e^{\xi_n} = 1$. Am I right?

Comment: @Thomas Yes....

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should be specific about probability spaces and filtrations and that you forgot integrability and adaptability.

Consider a filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr F, \{\mathscr F_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}, \mathbb P)$ where $\mathscr F_n = \mathscr F_n^{\xi} = \sigma(\xi_1, ..., \xi_n)$.

We want to show that $X_n = \exp{(\theta S_n-n \ln \phi(\theta))}$ is a $(\{\mathscr F_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}, \mathbb P)-$martingale.

---

1. $\exp{(\theta S_n-n \ln \phi(\theta))}$ is adapted to the filtration $\sigma(\xi_1, ..., \xi_n)$:

$\exp{(\theta S_n-n \ln \phi(\theta))}$ is a [Borel-measurable function of $S_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/887770), which is $\sigma(\xi_1, ..., \xi_n)$-measurable.

2. $\exp{(\theta S_n-n \ln \phi(\theta))}$ is integrable:

$E[|\exp{(\theta S_n-n \ln \phi(\theta))}|] = E[\exp{(\theta S_n-n \ln \phi(\theta))}] = 1 < \infty$

3. $\exp{(\theta S_n-n \ln \phi(\theta))}$ satisfies the martingale property:

Let m < n. Then

$$E[\exp{(\theta S_n-n \ln \phi(\theta))}|\mathscr F_m]$$

$$=E[\exp{(\theta (\xi_1 + ... + \xi_n)-n \ln \phi(\theta))}|\mathscr F_m]$$

$$=\exp{(\theta (\xi_1 + ... + \xi_m))} E[\exp{(\theta (\xi_{m+1} + ... + \xi_n)-n \ln \phi(\theta))}|\mathscr F_m]$$

$$=\exp{(\theta (\xi_1 + ... + \xi_m))} E[\exp{(\theta (\xi_{m+1} + ... + \xi_n)-n \ln \phi(\theta))}|\mathscr F_m]$$

$$=\exp{(\theta (\xi_1 + ... + \xi_m))} \exp{(-n \ln \phi(\theta))} E[\exp{(\theta (\xi_{m+1} + ... + \xi_n)})|\mathscr F_m]$$

$$=\exp{(\theta (\xi_1 + ... + \xi_m))} \exp{(-n \ln \phi(\theta))} E[\exp{(\theta (\xi_{m+1} + ... + \xi_n)})]$$

$$=\exp{(\theta (\xi_1 + ... + \xi_m))} \exp{(-n \ln \phi(\theta))} (E[\exp(\theta\xi_{m+1})] + ... + E[\exp(\theta \xi_{n}))])$$

$$=\exp{(\theta (\xi_1 + ... + \xi_m))} \exp{(-m \ln \phi(\theta))} \exp{(-(n-m) \ln \phi(\theta))} (E[\exp(\theta\xi_{m+1})] + ... + E[\exp(\theta \xi_{n}))])$$

$$=X_m \exp{(-(n-m) \ln \phi(\theta))} E[\exp(\theta\xi_{m+1})] + ... + E[\exp(\theta \xi_{n}))]$$

$$=X_m \exp{(-(n-m) \ln \phi(\theta))} E[\exp(\theta\xi_{m+1})] + ... + E[\exp(\theta \xi_{n}))]$$

$$=X_m \phi(\theta)^{-(n-m)} (E[\exp(\theta\xi_{m+1})] + ... + E[\exp(\theta \xi_{n}))])$$

$$=X_m \phi(\theta)^{-(n-m)} (\phi(\theta)^{(n-m)})$$

$$=X_m$$

QED