# How to show that: $X^{*}_n \sim X_n$ and $X^{*} \sim X$, then $E(h(X^{*}_n)) \to E(h(X^{*}))$ implies that $E(h(X_n)) \to E(h(X))$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

I am trying to show that if I have that $X^{*}_n \sim X_n$ and $X^{*} \sim X$, then $E(h(X^{*}_n)) \to E(h(X^{*}))$ implies that $E(h(X_n)) \to E(h(X))$, for $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a function that is bounded and continuous. What I tried to do was to rewrite the expectation as the Lebesgue integral with a limit in front, and then use the fact that $X^{*}_n \sim X_n$ implies $g(X^{*}_n) \sim g(X_n)$ for measurable functions $g$. However, I am not sure how to incorporate the CDF, which I want to use to specify equality in law, into the expectation. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Does $X_n^* \sim X_n$ mean that $X_n^*$ and $X_n$ have the same distribution?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not making that clear.

Comment: Then it is quite clear: If $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution then $E(X) = E(Y)$ consequently. In your case $E[h(X_n^*)] = E[h(X_n)]$ and $E[h(X^*)] = E[h(X)]$.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you!

Comment: @Solitary If X and Y are random variables with the same distribution, does that mean f(X) and f(Y) are random variables that have the same distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, [If X and Y are random variables with the same distribution, prove that f(X) and f(Y) are random variables that have the same distribution.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/887770/if-x-and-y-are-random-variables-with-the-same-distribution-prove-that-fx-and)

**Secondly, is $h$ Borel-measurable on $(\mathbb R, \mathscr B (\mathbb R))$?**

If the random variables are in $(\Omega, \mathscr F, \mathbb P)$ and take values in $(\mathbb R, \mathscr B (\mathbb R))$, I think we need $h$ to be Borel-measurable on $(\mathbb R, \mathscr B (\mathbb R))$

If so:

If $X_n^{*}$ and $X_n$ have the same distribution, then $h(X_n^{*})$ and $h(X_n)$ have the same distribution.

///ly, if $X^{*}$ and $X$ have the same distribution, then $h(X^{*})$ and $h(X)$ have the same distribution.

Hence, $E[h(X_n^{*})] = E[h(X_n)]$ and $E[h(X^{*})] = E[h(X)]$